# Cocos2d text list

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

This is kind of a confusing question, but I will try to describe it as best as I can.

What I want, is a box with a set size, and inside that box, a line of text will be added by the top. And as the app goes on, more lines will be added underneath the last line. As the text reaches the bottom of the box, it won't be shown until you scroll down the list of text. So in other words, I want all the lines of text to be contained in the box.

Also, I need a message to pop up when a certain line of text is clicked,

what's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When I did this in my Cocos2d iPhone application, I used an `NSTableView`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

There are some things you'll have to figure out to use a Cocoa interface class with Cocos2d, but it's worth it. If you want to see the results, it was in Crystal Shuffle that I used these.

The items can respond to touch events, and you can do popups when you get those events. I would also use Cocoa interface classes for that. In my case, I used the NSAlert class:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Example code for my use of UITableView, using Cocos2d version 0.99.3:

```
@interface MyMenu : CCLayer <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    UITableView* m_myTableView;
}

@implementation MyMenu
-(void) onEnter
{
    m_myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 120) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    m_myTableView.delegate = self;
    m_myTableView.dataSource = self;
    m_myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    m_myTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    m_myTableView.rowHeight = 27;
    m_myTableView.allowsSelection = NO;
}

-(void)onEnterTransitionDidFinish
{
    [super onEnterTransitionDidFinish];

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:m_myTableView];
    [m_myTableView release];
}
```

To be called before closing the Layer:

```
        NSArray *subviews = [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] subviews];
        for (id sv in subviews)
        {
            if(((UIView*)sv).tag == e_myTableTag)
            {
                [((UITableView*)sv) removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
```

You also need the relevant overloads, which you can look up in the Apple documentation:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this, anyway you can post some snippets on actually adding it to the cocos2d scene? I have added some pickerviews, I suppose it's probably close to that? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't have my code available; I may get time to add something like this tomorrow. The SE inbox system will alert me if you comment again, so do that if you don't hear from me by Saturday and you haven't figured it out yet. :)